# Wordpress Export Feature

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog on wordpress.com and I want to move it over to my private hosting. I have just attempted this and for some reason the export feature provided by Wordpress.com only exported posts from 2010, I did check all dates when asked. Also all of the posts text seems to be in the title and not separated. Is there something I am missing or will I have to edit every post by hand?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are exporting in the wordpress format, and also, try exporting a batch at a time (like a month per file). As the files may break, with extreamly large blogs.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like a good plan. At the moment the file type is a .xml when importing it asks for a WXR, but I can see no control over what format I can export from wordpress.com

Comment: Seems like it uses its 'default' wordpress format, the .xml is after the WXR format. You may want to refer to this link though...

http://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-a-blog/

Comment: If memory serve me right, just import the .xml file. The system (new version) will be able to detect it as WXR

Comment: Think your both right cheers. Now I just need to figure out why exporting and importing throws off the formatting so much! And seems to be putting the post into titles.

Comment: It would be nice if I could just export the entire MySQL database

Comment: I would rofl, if you manage to get their admin to do that for you.